# formatting Table of Content

Tags: table-of-contents

I am having trouble to arrange my TOC according to this format of writing. Please help me.
Thank you in advanced. The format mentioned as per attachment.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us please what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a line of text that says "table of contents", 3 lines of whitespace and than the actual table? You might want to consider changing the title of the table that comes with `\tableofcontents` and put a `\vspace{3em}` (see [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths) for distances that you can input).

For the white space at the top of the page, you might want to consider an empty figure that will be placed at the top of the page (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)), or also use the `\vspace{3em}` argument. If this type of layout has a name, there is a chance that someone already made a template (such as the `apa6` package, which will make it very easy to put your article into exact apa6 specifications)

Comment: Note that `1em` is the width of a `M` character, not the height of anything.

Comment: These are all somewhat poor suggestions.